Binary packet communication problem with socket.IOC++ client and node.js
From the node.js server
const binaryData = new Uint8Array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
socket.emit('message_test', binaryData.buffer);
console.log('Send packet');

I sent the packet to the client in this way
The client side using the socket.io library is not receiving packets.
bool packet::is_binary_message(string const& payload_ptr)
{
return payload_ptr.size()>0 && payload_ptr[0] == frame_message;
}

It is not recognized as a binary here. When sending using the socket.io library in node.js, it is said that the frame_type value and the type value are internally recognized and distinguished without explicitly.
As a test, I put the frame_type value and the type value in front of the buffer, and the client was able to receive the packet. What is the cause of the problem? Please help
I've tried this and that, but I don't know. Please help

If you debug a packet from a server from a client, you get two messages
payload "451-["MSG_TEST",{"_placeholder":true,"num":0}]"
payload "\x1\x2\x3\x4\x5"
It's coming in this way.
I only sent it once on the server, but I'm wondering why the client is dividing it into two. It's not even a big packet size.... I really don't know...
